# Postgres: Select one language version of the value from Multilanguage column

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a Postgres table where one of its column has jsonb type to store the Multilanguage value.
Here's the example.

```
|                   word                 |
|----------------------------------------|
|     {"en": "Hello", "es": "Hola"}      |
|     {"it": "Rosso", "es": "Rojo"}      |
|{"en": "Sea", "it": "Mare", "es": "Mar"}|
```

As you can see, the values do not always have all language version. My question is how I can select only the English version or any first value from json if the English version does not exist?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to unpack the JSON:

```
SELECT kv.value
FROM atable
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(atable.word) AS kv(key,value)
WHERE atable.id = ...
ORDER BY kv.key <> 'en'
LIMIT 1;
```

This relies on the fact that `FALSE < TRUE`.